Timestamp Handling yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss-HHMM
Anyone has any idea how I can read a csv with time like this:
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss-HHMM (e.g. “2022-05- 10T23:59:59.998-0400”) where the HHM is the offset in hours and minutes from UTC time.
so I can have:
Date (with just the day 2022-05-10)
Time (with just the time formatted correctly, we can drop the time zones)
Im working in python.
Thanks a lot in advance!
Everything I try gives an error :(((

It is formatted correctly - it is ISO 8601.

Please edit your question and share some code you've tried with the error(s) you get.

Pandas should be able to parse this format automatically and to detect the timezone:
pd.Timestamp('2022-05-10T23:59:59.998-0400')

# or
pd.to_datetime('2022-05-10T23:59:59.998-0400')
# Timestamp('2022-05-10 23:59:59.998000-0400', tz='UTC-04:00')

You can also use %z for the UTC offset:
pd.to_datetime('2022-05-10T23:59:59.998-0400', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')

